# Add folder with n albums with swift

Tags: ios, swift

I need to add a folder with some albums but not sure if programatically we are allow to do that. I'm using

```
PHAssetCollectionChangeRequest.creationRequestForAssetCollection(withTitle: albumName)
```

for creating the album and it works fine but is there a way to create a folder and add these albums?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
PHPhotoLibrary.shared().performChanges({
        PHAssetCollectionChangeRequest.creationRequestForAssetCollection(withTitle: "albumName")   // create an asset collection with the album name
    }) { success, error in
        if success {
    print("Album created succesfully")
        } else {
    print("Unable to create album")
        }
    }
```

Try this and if you get success than check photos you see album will be created.

Comment: yeah that works but that creates an album, what I need is to add a folder that can contain n albums.

Comment: sorry my mistake you need recursive album right?